# How is he? VS What is he like?

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

If we want to ask about a person's particular qualities, which of the following fits best?

> A. How should a teacher be like?
>
> B. How should be a teacher?
>
> C. What should a teacher be like?

To me, the third sounds best, since we are referring to the behavior of a teacher. We're not asking about his health.

Answer (score 1):

A. How should a teacher be like? [BUZZER]

B. How should be a teacher? [BUZZER]

Please note: In English How should and What should are followed by the subject, then the verb be.

C. What should a teacher be like? [OK]

A teacher should be **kind, patient and sympathetic.**
OR
A teacher should be **like a mentor**.

"What should a teacher "be like"? is better asked as:

How should a teacher be? The word *like* ***can create confusion*** as often it is interpreted to mean a comparison, when in everyday spoken language the use of **like** there is just asking for a description.

Answer (score -1):

> **How is he?**
>
> **What  is  he  like?**

First I would like to talk about your  title.

How  is he ?  means  how  is his  health.?

What  is he like?  means    how is  his   appearance?

I  think  how  should  be  a teacher   like?  is  wrong.

How  should be a teacher? means:

What  should  be the behaviour  of   a  teacher?

What  should  be  a teacher   like?

What  should  be  the   apperance  of  a teacher?

Comment: How should be  a teacher. is wrong, too.  What should and How should + subject + be.